# Encryption is not the same using the same method to encrypt the same plaintext

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, passwords

Use the same method below to encrypt the same plaintext twice,but the ciphertext are not the same after encryption.Why?

I want to encrypt my password when saving user information to database,and use the encryption method below.But I want to complete the edit-user feature,after inputing the old password and new password,find out the user according to the selected userid, and encrypt the old password,try to validate the old password typed is matched the password stored in database.But they never matched even though I input the right password.So is there any way to encrypt the password and validate if they are the same after using the same method to encrypt the password.

```
    //encrypt the plainText
    public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText == "")
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        var temp = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

        byte[] encrypted = ProtectedData.Protect(temp, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [MSDN documentation of the ProtectedData class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx), it looks like it is performing 2-way encryption using a machine- or user-specific key. That means that if the machine or user that is active checking the key is different than the machine that originally encrypted it, you will get garbage results. If you only want to check the validity of a password, I would suggest a 1-way esecure hashing algorithm instead of 2-way encryption that supports decryption. Other posts on StackOverflow talk about using secure hashing algorithms ([What is the most secure hashing algorithm in the .NET framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242648/what-is-the-most-secure-hashing-algorithm-in-the-net-framework)).

**Edit:** I haven't tested this code on various systems under various users, but I expect it would work more universally because I don't expect that it is based on a machine or user key.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
byte[] hashed = sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args[0]));
Console.WriteLine("Hash of {0}={1}", args[0], Convert.ToBase64String(hashed));
```

**Edit 2:** I would also add that my understanding of cryptography also suggests that you should probably include some "salt" in your hashed value. In other words, add something (like the user name) to the end of the password string before hashing it (both when entered and when checked) so that users with the same password don't end up with the same hash value, for example.

Comment: I think he really wants a hash (he's comparing two encrypted strings)... What you are saying is correct, and my answer is correct too... But I have a feeling the first person to post a hashing technique for the guy will get the points ;)

Comment: A single round of SHA256 is really insufficient, it's better than a single round of SHA1, but not a lot better. A library like [BCrypt](https://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) is a much more dummy-proof solution to password hashing.

Comment: Yes, although I am moderately familiar with how encryption works, I should clarify that I am not a security expert, so if the degree of security is important to you, I would encourage you to research the algorithm you use in place of my SHA256 example. The code I provide is only an example of using 1 way hashing and not necessarily a representation of which form of hashing is most secure or advisable. (+1 on the caution comment.)

Comment: @Syon BTW, from what I can tell, SHA256 is a sufficient improvement over SHA1 if I infer correctly from articles like http://hungred.com/useful-information/php-better-hashing-password/ and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897434/password-security-sha1-sha256-or-sha512

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: To be frank, the authors of those articles are giving out bad information (in not explicitly recommending more than 1 round). The issue is not the quality of the hash algorithm, but the amount of time and resources it takes to compute the hash. I won't get in to a big thing about why, but [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/4691) sums it up.

Answer (score 1):

Some randomness in the output is actually a [feature for encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector).

You get two choices:

- If you ever need to recover the password from its encrypted form as part of your requirements, use encryption as you do, but decipher the result before making the comparison between expected and entered password.
- If you don't really need to recover the password, use a hash algorithm instead (with a suitable salt). You'll be able to compare the two hashed values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I threw together in a Console application.  The Ciphers will not match, but as you can see, you can decrypt them just fine :)

```
class Program
{
    private static string salt = "My Salt Brings All The Boys To The Yard... Wait A Second.....";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; 0 < 20; i++)
        {
            string password = "Guess my password!";

            string cipher = Encrypt(password, salt);

            string decipher = Decrypt(cipher, salt);

            Console.WriteLine(decipher);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static public string Encrypt(string password, string salt)
    {
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);

        byte[] cipherBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(passwordBytes, saltBytes, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes);
    }

    static public string Decrypt(string cipher, string salt)
    {
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipher);
        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);

        byte[] passwordBytes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(cipherBytes, saltBytes, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(passwordBytes);
    }
}
```